# Primefaces Calendar does not show up

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, websphere

I am trying to integrate Primefaces 5.2 to a JSF application which has version of 2.0.11-02. I am using IBM WebSphere 8.5.5 as application server. I am trying to use p:calendar in my page but it does not show up.

When I checked from Google Chrome Dev Tools, I noticed that the corresponding input field has no "click" event listener attached to it. In Primefaces Showcase the input fields has "click" event listener so when you click, calendar shows up.
I am also having the same trouble with sorting of datatable. The column has no "click" event listener, so it does not send any request when the header of a sortable column is clicked.
Please help me with that problem.

P.S: The application I am working on was a JSF 1.2 application and were using JWL libraries of IBM. Since I am upgrading the application to JSF 2, I am not able to use that library anymore. That's way I am trying to integrate Primefaces. primefaces-5.2.jar is placed under /WEB-INF/lib and I also still have jsf-ibm.jar, odc-jsf.jar in that directory.

Comment: Hard to say anything about content which you cannot see. It is going to be as simple as a mistake in the xhtml logic.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not allowed to share any code out from my company, I wish I could.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and hopefully do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a lib folder out of the meta-inf and PrimeFaces put the library, or you could also try creating a page with the component PrimeFaces calendar to see if it works and put in

```
<html xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you save your XHTML file with proper extension? If you have deafult settings it would be *.jsp as far as I remember

Comment: I am saving the file as *.xhtml and also the Primefaces components are rendered to html properly, but only the events are not attached as far as I observe.